# Custom Order a Nested Dictionary (or Set) in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, set

I receive the following set from AWS:

```
{
'AWS/EC2': 
{'CPUCreditBalance','NetworkOut','StatusCheckFailed_System','NetworkPacketsOut','NetworkPacketsIn','CPUSurplusCreditBalance','CPUUtilization','CPUSurplusCreditsCharged','StatusCheckFailed','DiskReadOps','DiskWriteOps','DiskWriteBytes','DiskReadBytes','StatusCheckFailed_Instance','CPUCreditUsage', 'NetworkIn'}, 
'System/Windows': {
'MemoryUtilization', 'Paging File % Usage', 'LogicalDisk % Free Space'
}
}
```

I need to be able to custom order the `keys` that are in the set `'AWS/EC2'` so that they always are in this order:
`keyorder = ['StatusCheckFailed','CPUUtilization','DiskReadOps', 'DiskWriteOps','NetworkIn' ]`

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to specify the order so  that we when we write the JSON for the Cloudwatch dashboard, the values will always be in the same location across many dashboards.

Sample output:

```
{
   "widgets":[
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":0,
         "y":9,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkPacketsOut",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkPacketsOut",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkPacketsOut",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":6,
         "y":9,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkPacketsIn",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkPacketsIn",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkPacketsIn",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":12,
         "y":9,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskReadOps",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskReadOps",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskReadOps",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":18,
         "y":9,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskReadBytes",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskReadBytes",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskReadBytes",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":0,
         "y":10,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "StatusCheckFailed_Instance",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "StatusCheckFailed_Instance",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "StatusCheckFailed_Instance",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":6,
         "y":10,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskWriteBytes",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskWriteBytes",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskWriteBytes",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":12,
         "y":10,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "CPUUtilization",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "CPUUtilization",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "CPUUtilization",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":18,
         "y":10,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskWriteOps",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskWriteOps",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "DiskWriteOps",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":0,
         "y":11,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "StatusCheckFailed_System",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "StatusCheckFailed_System",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "StatusCheckFailed_System",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":6,
         "y":11,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "StatusCheckFailed",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "StatusCheckFailed",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "StatusCheckFailed",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":12,
         "y":11,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkOut",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkOut",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkOut",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":18,
         "y":11,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkIn",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkIn",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "AWS/EC2",
                  "NetworkIn",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":0,
         "y":12,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "System/Windows",
                  "Paging File % Usage",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "System/Windows",
                  "Paging File % Usage",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "System/Windows",
                  "Paging File % Usage",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":6,
         "y":12,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "System/Windows",
                  "MemoryUtilization",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "System/Windows",
                  "MemoryUtilization",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "System/Windows",
                  "MemoryUtilization",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"metric",
         "x":12,
         "y":12,
         "width":6,
         "height":6,
         "properties":{
            "view":"timeSeries",
            "stacked":false,
            "metrics":[
               [
                  "System/Windows",
                  "LogicalDisk % Free Space",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "System/Windows",
                  "LogicalDisk % Free Space",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ],
               [
                  "System/Windows",
                  "LogicalDisk % Free Space",
                  "InstanceId",
                  "i-XXXXXX"
               ]
            ],
            "region":"us-west-2"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a dict. Dicts by definition don't have an order. If order really is important to you, use lists.

```
{
   'a': 1,
   'b': 2,
   'c': 3
}
```

should get changed to this if order matters:

```
[
   ['a', 1],
   ['b', 2],
   ['c', 3]
]
```

or, cleaner:

```
[
   {key: 'a', value: 1},
   {key: 'b', value: 2},
   {key: 'c', value: 3}
]
```

---

*Edit:* it seems Python 3.6+ dictionaries are ordered based on insertion order.
Further, using a OrderedDict might solve your problem (maybe).

Comment: Python 3.5 and above, dictionaries are in the order inserted/declared.